# Data classification model to detect a process in an event log

Tags: classification, pattern-recognition

There are many example in python which has a ready made data set, for example there is T-Shirt pre-trained data and thousands images, within few minutes it will tell how many t-shirt images are there in those folders

but how that data `detect.tflite` itself is created from scratch step by step, If I wanted to manually write those data in csv how it should be done

Ultimately I have data which says, click event, keyboard event, process `exe` name, title of the window, and timestamp

I want to detect what exactly that user doing in his computer, who told do to what to him I want the software to tell me in words and diagrams

this is definitely a big software, but data classification part unclear to me

I need some guidance